# Network interface name has with at sign - what is it?

Tags: network-interface, lxc

I am trying to hunt down information for why a network interface name would have an at sign, but there's too much noise in the results I am so far getting (I lack the correct terminology to search on)

I have a LXC container on a Ubuntu host. Inside the container I run and get:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: eth0@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:37:a0:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.0.3.195/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe37:a07a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Note that `eth0@if10`

What is this `@` portion called / referring to?

On the host there is no such `if10`, another container I have has an `eth0@if8` - I must assume this is part of LXC's/containers' handling of network translations somehow, but I had not noticed this existing previously, and wonder if it's a complement to bridging, that might exist in other scenarios ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`eth0@if10` means:

- your network interface is named still simply `eth0` and network tools and apps can only refer to this name, without the @ appendix. (As a sidenote, this is most probably a veth peer, but the name does not need to reflect this.)
- `@if10` means: `eth0` is connected to some (other) network interface with index 10 (decimal). Since there is also a `link-netnsid 0` shown, this other network interface is in another network namespace (kind of virtual IP stack), presumably the root (a.k.a. host) network namespace.

If you use `ip link show` in your host, and not in your container, then one of the network interfaces listed there should have an `@9` appendix; the interface name will probably start with `veth...`. This interface is the peer to the `eth0@10` interface you asked about. Veth interfaces come in pairs connected to each other, like a virtual cable.

So, the `@...` is an appendix created by the `ip` tool, and it is not part of Linux' network interface names. The number after the @ refers to another network interface with the index number that is shown after the @. The index numbers are printed before the network interface names, such as in `9: eth0@if10`. The peer network interface can be in a different network namespace.

Unfortunately, finding the correct network namespace for the `link-netnsid ..` is rather involved, see [how to find the network namespace of a veth peer ifindex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441876/how-to-find-the-network-namespace-of-a-veth-peer-ifindex).

**UPDATE 2023:** Siemens has now released [Edgeshark](https://github.com/siemens/edgeshark) as OSS that provides a nice graphical web UI rendering the relationships of network interfaces in containers, the host, et cetera.

Comment: Thanks - following that explanation it looks like what I'm looking at is what's properly called "network namespaces". Ta.

Comment: The @ notation is also used in other situations not related to network namespaces, such as MACVLAN interfaces attached to another physical network interface. It's the `link-netnsid 0` that signals that another network namespace is involved. The @ just says that there another interface involved, but not where that other interface is.

Answer (score 0):

Check for a file like 70-persistent-net.rules under /etc/udev/rules.d or under /lib/udev/rules.d.  There should be a line with the network interface name and MAC address.  Altering that and rebooting should rename the NIC.

Comment: I'm not trying to rename the NIC - I'm trying to understand what is present....

Comment: Understood.  But is there a persistent-net rules file with the "at" sign in the NIC name?

Comment: The @ sign is in this case not part of the interface name, but instead an artefact of the `ip` tool. Just compare with `ifconfig` ... or do some quick Python script dumping interface names using `pyroute2`. All will show there un-adorned real network interface names.